# VirtualPathProvider Not working in asp .net website project

Tags: asp.net

Here is the scenario :

1) Created on Web Application project for reusable user controls

2) Created Main application where i want to load these controls dynamically (definitely from assembly)

The above scenario worked wonderfully well, as i have selected web application project for main application

but now i want to use same reusable control project in asp .net website project but its not working, it is providing me error like

The virtual path '/App_Resource/ReflectionControl.DUControl.ascx' maps to another application, which is not allowed.

Below is the steps which i have followed to do it...

[Link](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/tips-tricks/aspnet-reusing-web-user-controls-and-forms-000915.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the issue... "/App_Resource/ReflectionControl.DUControl.ascx"

Here You need to provide path like "~/App_Resource/ReflectionControl.DUControl.ascx"

So, "~" was missing...it rocks.